# GET flash memory type: SLC or MLC

Tags: usb, usb-drive, flash-memory

Just for my knowledge, I would like to know whether the type of flash memory used in my pendrive is SLC or MLC. Is there a way to find it out? I googled but found nothing.

Comment: Unless it's a high-end drive, it's definitely MLC.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer was given by Mechanical Snail(check the comments above). The answer's brief and simple, every Flash device uses a MLC because it is cheap and has a higher density. Giving SLC to the customer would make the pendrive costly as cost per gigabyte for SLC is more than MLC. For uses like these MLC is always preferred over SLC.